# API Key based authentication with NGNIX open source API Gateway

Tags: authentication, nginx, api-key, api-gateway

Does NGINX open source version support API authentication via API Key. Basically looking for below functionality -

1. In NGINX configuration, configure mapping b/w API Key and one or more endpoints it has access to.
2. Configure certain endpoints for API Key based authentication.
3. For configured API endpoints, extract API Key from header and compare against mapping.